# schema validation error occuring on localserver but not on github - Swagger

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

I am getting a schema validation error when i host my SWAGGER.JSON file on my local server that runs the swagger.html.
But, when i put the file in 
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/novastorm123/abapswaggerNW7.0/master/swagger_70.json
It works.
I don't get any console error in both cases.

I treid to disable the online validator error from swagger.
I used

```
validatorUrl : null
```

But it is not working and i am still getting the error at the bottom of the page.
[image]

On clicking of the error i am getting the message

```
{"schemaValidationMessages":[{"level":"error","message":"Can't read from file 
/api/swagger.json"}]}
```

Whenever i am pasting my JSON in the online editor, it is accepting it as a valid JSON Input

Comment: Which version of Swagger UI - 2 or 3?

Comment: @Helen Swagger 2.0

Comment: I deployed a Swagger UI 2.x distribution about a month ago (before the master branch became 3.x).  In my case, `validatorUrl: null` works as expected.

Comment: @DaveDelay When i host my json file on github and refer it, its working.